# Trying to plot a KDE Map - (points = coordinates) not recognised as an argument

Tags: r, rstudio

```
library(ks)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sp)

setwd("/Users/user/Desktop/Thesis/DATA/")

data <- read.csv("whalesharks.csv")

coordinates <- data[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")]

kde <- kde(coordinates)

density_spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(x = coordinates,
                                       data = data.frame(density = kde$estimate),
                                       proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

plot(density_spdf, col = heat.colors(100), pch = 20, cex = 0.6, main = "KDE Map")
```

Comment: Hi Kadir, thanks for your help - I have tried running with 'x = coordinates' but this didn't seem to work either?